# background images is not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

So what I am trying to do is first giving a container a background image and then creating two div tag using col-md-6 of bootstrap. background image of main div is just grass texture. In the two div tag I am giving a background image of skeleton of football court. So I am taking one half giving it to one div and then taking the same image transforming 180. But it's not coming as expected. Don't know what going wrong here.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

.height{
width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
background-image: url(./turf2.jpg);
}
.left{
background-image: url(./court.png);
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 768px;
}
.right{
background-image: url(./court.png);
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 768px;
transform: rotate(180deg);
}


</style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="row height">

<div class="col-md-6 left">

</div>
<div class="col-md-6 right">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: use console of browser and check the correct hieght by adjusting it from there.

Comment: could you host the images so that we can check through fiddle ?

Comment: background-position: center center;

Answer (score 0):

You can write as

```
 .right {
     background-image: url(./court.png);
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     height: 768px;
    -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform:scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform:scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform:scaleX(-1);
    transform:scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your image dimensions again to make sure they match. See here that I have used two images with the same dimensions and they align perfectly.

```css
.height {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(./turf2.jpg);
}
.left {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.right {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div class="row height">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 left">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 right">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't changed your code, just replace by a simple picture.
It works well, maybe you should check dimensions of court.png file.

[image: my image file]

[image: test result]

Answer (score 0):

First its a very bad practice to use bootstrap row class with any other class, instead you should add your class below the row class. Here's a way you can get the images align perfectly, just change the html part of your code to following.

```
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="height">
       <div class="col-md-6 left">

       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 right">

       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```